# Stream live camera feed from RPI compute module to RPI 3

Tags: c++, opencv, camera, raspberry-pi, computer-vision

I'm developing a portable hardware/software application to use 2 cameras in a stereo vision configuration, and process the raw data for information to output.

For this reason I have a Raspberry pi Compute module kit, and a Raspberry pi 3.

- The compute module kit will operate the two cameras
- The pi 3 will run the code as it has the computational power
- OpenCV (C++) is the preferred CV package

As this is a portable application, internet based streaming is not a suitable option.

I've not had time to play around with the GPIO pins, or find a method of streaming the two camera feeds from the compute module to the pi 3.

How would you suggest I proceed with this? Has anyone performed such a project? What links can you provide to help me implement this?

This is for a dissertation project, and will hopefully help in the long run when developing as a full prototype.

- Frame Size: 640x480
- Frame Rate: 15 fps
- The cameras are 5cm apart from each other

Comment: There isn't enough information to answer your question. How far apart are the devices? Signals skew and distort over distance. What frame sizes are you using? How many pixels and how many bits per pixel? What frame rate do you need to achieve in frames/sec? GPIO is unlikely to exceed a few kilobits/sec. I2C unlikely to exceed 300kbits/sec.

Comment: I guess your best option is to make a wired Ethernet connection between your devices (100 Mbits/s), or an ad hoc wifi network which will probably max out at 60 Mbits/sec.

Comment: If I was to establish a wired connection, I'd need to add a USB to ethernet adapter to the compute module as it has no onboard ethernet. Same goes for wifi.

This does not make it impossible, but I could try this.

Comment: With this in mind, how would I be able to view the data stream of the cameras via an ethernet connection?

Comment: In the real application, I guess you would use a socket - the camera would take a photo and send the data to the compute node via a socket and the compute node would read the socket and do some OpenCV work on it and display it with `imshow()`or a Qt-type of GUI. In the short term, for testing, you could use `netcat` or `nc` to blast frames between Raspberry Pis.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated Answer**

I have been doing some further tests on this. Using the `iperf` tool and my own simple TCP connection code as well, I connected two Raspberry Pis directly to each other over wired Ethernet and measured the TCP performance.

Using the standard, built-in 10/100 interface on a Raspberry Pi 2 and a Raspberry Pi 3, you can achieve 94Mbits/s.

If, however, you put a TRENDnet USB3 Gigabit adaptor on each Pi, and repeat the test, you can get 189Mbits/s and almost 200 if you set the MTU to 4088.

**Original Answer**

I made a quick test - not a full answer - but more than I can add as a comment or format correctly!

I set up 2 Raspberry Pi 2s with a wired Ethernet connection. I took a 640x480 picture on one as a JPEG - and it came out at 178,000 bytes.

Then, on the receiving Pi, I set up to receive 1,000 frames. Like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
for ((i=0;i<1000;i++)); do
   echo $i
   nc -l 1234 > pic-${i}.jpg
done
```

On the sending Pi, I set up to transit the picture 1,000 times:

```
for ((i=0;i<1000;i++)) ; do nc 192.168.0.65 1234 < pipic1.jpg ;done
```

That took 34 seconds, so it does 33 fps roughly but it stuttered a lot because of writing to the filesystem and therefore SD card. So, I removed the

nc -l 1234 > pic-${i}.jpg

and didn't write the data to disk - which is what you will need as you are writing to the screen, as follows:

```
nc -l 1234 > /dev/null
```

Comment: It been a while since I asked this question. I'll start by saying thank you for the help. What you've provided is very helpful. I will be taking my project one step further when the new rpi cm3 comes out, and building a board that holds 2 modules, and have them communicate with an on-board gigabit connection, if the modules support it, need to wait for the full specs.

Just thought I'd give you an update :)